# Excel VBA - Saving A Series of Charts into one GIF picture for the animation effect

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use VBA programming to save a a series of charts in Excel into one GIF picture for the animation effect. Is there any solution?

The below is a related question which address the issue of saving a chart into a GIF file one by one without any animation effect.
[Excel VBA - Saving Charts as GIF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482807/excel-vba-saving-charts-as-gif-files)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like VBA cannot export animated gifs itself, which makes for an interesting programming challenge. You have two options:

## Make the GIF file yourself

The GIF specification doesn't look hard. In fact, [here's a guy who says it's easy to implement it in VBA.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?547147-creating-animated-gifs-in-visual-basic-6&s=19c29db8fc91a94609dd76ceac7854af&p=3380874&viewfull=1#post3380874) If you have time and are coding for learning or for fun, I'd attempt this. If you're hard pressed, try the next suggestion.

## Call a third-party tool from your code

Have a free tool like [Gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) do the job for you ([download the Windows port](https://eternallybored.org/misc/gifsicle/)). In your code, when it's time to create the resulting GIF, instead of something like

```
call CreateGif("result.gif", "input1.gif", "input2.gif", "input3.gif")
```

You will externally call the `.exe` tool, like:

```
call Shell("C:\path\to\gifsicle.exe input1.gif input2.gif input3.gif > result.gif")
```

Note that you'll probably need to fiddle with quoting paths and generally building the command line correctly (you'll use a loop if the number of input GIFs is variable). Read [Gifsicle's man page](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/man.html) for usage details.